# Input of length greater than 255 in postgresql rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, postgresql, validation

I have a field with datatype string in the rails Postgresql table. What happens when I enter value more than 255. Does the Postgresql cut the string to 255 characters or does it prohibits from entering?

Comment: Please find and read the documentation before posting questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/datatypes/text](http://www.sqllines.com/postgresql/datatypes/text)

> ...for example, VARCHAR(255) does not allow inserting a string more than 255 characters long.

**It won't truncate the string for you, and it will fail if you try to insert one.**

Answer (score 1):

Postgres will throw an error if you try to write a value longer than the field's limit: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-character.html

Here's something you can do (with a migration) if you need bigger limits and want to control it instead of using `text` type:
`change_column :table, :column, :string, limit: 510`

Comment: I think this answer is better than the one from barnacle.m as it links the original docs instead of a secondary source that could be wrong.